# Ask for certain number of inputs based on integer input

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I really don't even know how to ask this question properly, but I'm assigned an assignment that asks me to ask a user for an input (in this case, it's a number of sheep).  Then, after they input a number, say 5, I am supposed to ask the user to assign an x and y coordinate value based on that integer that they input.  My current theory is to store the original number in an array and then somehow ask the user how many coordinates (or set of 2 numbers) based on their value.

I don't really have any idea how to begin this but I will attach my code thus far.

```
private int x, y;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sheepScanner = new Scanner(System.in); //Allows for user input
    System.out.println("Enter a number of Sheep"); //Asks user for input


    int numSheep = sheepScanner.nextInt(); //reads in number of sheep and stores it in variable numSheep
    int totalSheep[] = new int[numSheep]; //creates an array called totalSheep based on numSheep
    //System.out.println(totalSheep);
        for (int i = 1; i < totalSheep.length; i++) {
            totalSheep[i]=Integer.parseInt(); //literally no idea what's going here
```

Answer (score 0):

based on what i understood What you need to do is just take the input from the user and store it in a vector/array. Then based on the value entered just run a loop and add it to a map.

```
HashMap<Integer,String> map= new HashMap<>();
```

Then run a for loop till the number i.e

```
for(int i=0;i<numberOfSheep;i++)
{
double x-Cordinate="";//store your values here
double y-Cordinate="";//store your values here
String co-ordinates= x-Cordinate +","+y-Cordinate;
map.put(i,co-ordinates);
}
```

Now you will have a map with co-ordinates and sheep number. You can get the key and values from it. e.g If you want sheep number 5 co-ordinate from the
map then you can use. `map.get(sheepNumber)` . If you want t separate values from the cordinates then use `split(",")` Hope I have answered what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

use this in last line

```
totalSheep[i]=i;
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I correctly understood what you are trying to do is basically to ask the user for a number of sheeps and then for each one of the sheeps to ask for the x and y coordinates (of this sheep?).

So the first thing you do is to ask for the number of sheeps and store it to `numSheep`, this looks fine.

Then you create an array. What you really need here is probably a two-dimensional array like

```
int[][] coordinates = new int[sheepNum][2];
```

So it will be an array holding 5 arrays, each one of length 2. Those will be the (x,y) coordinates, as many as the user entered. If the user entered 5, this array will hold 5 sets of (x,y) coordinates.

Then you start your loop from 0 to the length of this array, this is also fine.

```
for (int i = 1; i < coordinates.length; i++) { ... }
```

Notice that `coordinates.length` is just `sheepNum`, because the array holds `sheepNum` elements (x-y-pairs).

Inside of this loop you have the variable `i`, which runs from `0` to `sheepNum` and which is kindof the number of the current sheep.

And so after all what you need to do inside of this loop is to fill the array.

So read another two integers (the `x` and `y` of the sheep number `i`)

And store these values to `coordinate[i][0]` and `coordinate[i][1]`.

Done :)

Comment: So how would that look in terms of the information within the loop?  So basically, the only difference is just a 2 dimensional array instead of 1.  What would I do within the loop after that?  The 'totalSheep[i]=Integer.parseInt()' doesn't work.

Comment: coordinate[i][0] = sheepScanner.nextInt(); and coordinate[i][1] = sheepScanner.nextInt(); So the user enters the x and y of this sheep. Nothing more.

Comment: Do you just initialize coordinate as an integer up?